# Why do STL algorithms require two iterators explicitly?

Tags: c++, user-interface, stl

Several algorithms in the C++ STL require to specify explicitly two iterators. For example, sorting a `std::vector<T> v` is done with `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end())`. Since processing the entire container (e.g. with `std::sort`, `std::find`, etc.) is a fairly common situation, I'm wondering why a simple version of these algorithms that accepts just the container is not implemented. I mean something like `std::sort(v)`, that uses `v.begin()` and `v.end()` iterators by default.

Is there some underlying technical reason that I'm not aware of? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's possible since C++20 with _ranges_: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/sort.

Comment: The use of iterators makes the functions more portable with more containers. If you make your own container with a fully functional iterator, it will automatically work with functions like `std::sort`.

Comment: By using iterator pairs it's also possible to use these function with pointers (and arrays).

Comment: iterators are not necesarrily bound to a container.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm wondering why a simple version of these algorithms that accepts just the container is not implemented.

It was, in C++20, with `std::ranges` versions.

> Is there some underlying technical reason that I'm not aware of?

Sort of. When the algorithms in `<algorithm>` were first proposed, distinguishing between different cases in templates was possible, but it was rather unwieldy.

How do you distinguish, from the call site, which of these templates fits?

```
template <typename InIt, typename OutIt, typename Func>
OutIt transform(InIt, InIt, OutIt, Func); // unary transform on iterator

template <typename Lhs, typename Rhs, typename OutIt, typename Func>
OutIt transform(Lhs, Rhs, OutIt, Func); // binary transform on containers
```

Comment: also by concept of iterators it's impossible to get `end()` from iterator returned by `begin()`, so whole range function wouldn't have same semantic as begin-end one, e.g.  `sort(container)` vs. `sort(begin_iterator, end_iterator)`, and the former wouldn't be applicable to arrays\pointers. Perhaps author of original STL (Morozov) deemed such inconsistency confusing. ISO just followed the pre-existing library

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie? I don't follow. The container overload of `sort` would be defined "equivalent to `sort(begin(container), end(container))`"

Comment: you can DO that now, but SHOULD you do that while designing an API that can be understood and code created would be  transparent to someone who is less familiar with every overload?  Library was designed in times when C++ wasn't standardized, sizeof behavior was slightly different too. And there was no `std::begin`, `std::end` in STL. Array version of sort operation on array `arr` would be  `sort(arr, arr + size_of_array)`. Should it be a C-style, `sort(arr, size_of_array)`? You can say that design of those functions is historical. ranges library appeared as attempt to rewrite rules.

Comment: `std::begin`, `std::end` are introduced in ISO C++11 and even in that time some implementation didn't overload them for arrays btw.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie the array case would be the easiest to distinguish. `sort(T(&arr)[N])` would be defined as `sort(arr, arr+N)`. I wasn't talking about *users* having to distinguish, I was talking about writing the overloads with C++98 era tools such that there aren't ambiguous call sites.

Comment: @Caleth That won't work if the array is decayed.

Comment: @김선달 if you have *one* pointer, you don't have a range, and it should rightly instantiate none of the overloads. If you have two pointers, you have *by definition* two iterators

Comment: @Caleth: *"How do you distinguish, from the call site"*. `std::vector`'s constructor (might) have same issue: `std::vector<T> v(a, b);` is a-b a range from iterator, or a is size and b is the fill-element? SFINAE could already be used in C++98, Alternatively, we might also have different name  (and for constructor tags) (or namespaces for functions).

Comment: @Jarod42 I agree. That's why I said possible but unwieldy.

Comment: @김선달 moreof, it didn't work that way pre-98, and STL is pre-98 :P

Comment: @Caleth note, that all those are header-only libraries. Adding new entities and complex sfinae branches you increase compilation time. As someone who works with projects consisting of 10k+ files, I would prefer spending a second typing extra argument, rather than waiting several extra minutes on every build. A problem of semantic of code is still exist. I would rather see a `std::sort_container(expression-returning-a-container)`, rather than `std::sort(expression-returning-a-container)`. As I happen to had shared acquitances with Morozov, I can tell, that they had similar thoughts.